# Automatic Nullable to non nullable conversion operator for system structs/classes

Tags: c#

I am attempting to convert a huge project away from using XSD's to using entities, but a problem with this is that XSD's did not generate `Nullable` types, they generated non-nullable types and generated methods such as `IsMyFieldNameNull()`.

I would like to have our entities work properly and be nullable types, but i would not like to go round the (400,000 SLOC) project and add  `.Value` to all instance of every access to an entity property.

I came up with:

```
namespace System
{
    public partial struct Int64
    {
        public static explicit operator Int64(Int64? d)
        {
            return (d.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

But am being given the error "Conversion operator with same parameter and return types". Does anybody know how to best work around this, and if the code above is even possible?

Comment: No, code like that isn't possible: `partial` has to be in the same assembly, for one. Some other solution will be the way to go.

Comment: anyway, what would happen if `d` were `null`. Show us a type that implements one of the `IsMyFieldNameNull()` properties.

Comment: https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator  would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, maintain backwards compatibility with existing code, good practice with future code. I came up with the following code:

```
public class Auto<T> where T: struct
{
    private T? _value;

    public Auto()
    {
        _value = default(T);
    }

    public Auto(T val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }

    public Auto(T? val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _value.HasValue;
        }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value.HasValue ? _value.Value : default(T); }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Auto<T> d)
    {
        return d._value.HasValue ? d._value.Value : default(T);
    }

    public static implicit operator Auto<T>(T d)
    {
        return new Auto<T>(d);
    }

    public static implicit operator T?(Auto<T> d)
    {
        return (d._value);
    }

    public static implicit operator Auto<T>(T? d)
    {
        return new Auto<T>(d);
    }
}
```

To be used:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public Auto<long> ID;
    public Auto<short> Status;
    public String Name;

   //rest of entity code here
}
```

This way, i do not have to go around the existing code base adding `.HasValue`'s and `.Values` everywhere, and i also dont have to use `IsStatusNull()` (though these methods are required for compatibility reasons, they will simply return `HasValue`).

Not sure how helpful this would be to others, but this is the most sensible way of creating my new DAL layer to replace my old bad DAL layer, and having to change as little as possible in the existing BLL and App layers.